# SQL SERVER Calculos matematicos con variables

Tags: sql, variables, table, server

Estimados: Necesito una mano tengo un ST donde tengo

```
    @archivo1 nvarchar (500),  
    @archivo2 nvarchar (500),
    @COEFiCIENTE  int,
    @script nvarchar (500)
```

-- donde las variables @archivo corresponde al nombre de una TABLA y las 2 TABLAS tienen los mismos nombres de campos. y se pretende

> GENERAR UN LISTADO CON REGISTROS DEL ARCHIVO2 CUYO COINCIDENCIA DE ID
> ENTRE LAS DOS TABLAS "Y" QUE EL VALOR DEL CAMPO2 DEL ARCHIVO2 SEA
> MAYOR O IGUAL QUE EL CAMPO2 DEL ARCHIVO1 MULTIPLICADO POR LA VARIABLE
> COEFICIENTE.

YO SIN MUCHA EXPERIENCIA EN VARIABLES AL CORRER EL SQL TIRA ERROR, PERO NO ME DICE CUAL ES EL ERROR.

(No column name)
error

SE AGRADECE LA AYUDA UTILICE EL SIGUIENTE CODIGO:

```
    SET @Script = N'SELECT * 
        FROM [Base].[dbo].['+ @ARCHIVO1 + '],[Base].[dbo].['+ @ARCHIVO2+ ']
        WHERE ([Base].[dbo].['+ @ARCHIVO1 + '].[ID] = [Base].[dbo].['+ @ARCHIVO2 + '].[ID])  AND   
    ([Base].[dbo].['+ @ARCHIVO1 + '].[campo2] > = SUM ([Base].[dbo].['+ @ARCHIVO2 + '].[campo2]) * ‘+ 
            @COEFiCIENTE + ’)'
        
    EXEC (@Script)
```

Comment: Te aconsejo jamás utilizar "Select * " puede ahorrar tiempo pero no dolores de cabeza, segundo, utilizar joins explicitos (Inner, left, right..) con su correspondiente clausula "ON", puede inducir errores o desoptimizar la consulta, y tecero, tienes una funcion agregada DENTRO de la clausula WHERE (iría en el HAVING) y sin GROUP BY (y el "select * " te obligaría a no tener funciones agregadas)

Answer (score 0):

Una de las posibilidades que tienen las querys dinámicas antes de ejecutarlas, es que las puedes lanzar mediante un simple print, para saber cual es el error, ya que la misma luego la pegas en la ventana del editor y el intellisense te indica cual puede ser el problema.

Además en el código que has pegado tienes areas de mejora con la sintaxis, ya que actualmente se utiliza para relacionar las tablas on y no la manera "viejuna" Where.

```
declare 
    @archivo1 nvarchar (500) = N'A',  
    @archivo2 nvarchar (500) = N'B',
    @COEFiCIENTE  varchar(10) = '0',
    @script nvarchar (500);

SET @Script = 
    N'SELECT * 
            FROM [Base].[dbo].['+ @ARCHIVO1 + '] as a 
                 inner join [Base].[dbo].['+ @ARCHIVO2+ '] as b 
                 on a.id = b.id
        WHERE  
    b.[campo2] > = (a.[campo2] * (Cast( '+ 
            @COEFiCIENTE + ' as int))))'
        
    PRINT @SCRIPT
```

> SELECT *
> FROM [Base].[dbo].[A] as a
> inner join [Base].[dbo].[B] as b
> on a.id = b.id
> WHERE
> b.[campo2] > = (a.[campo2] * (Cast( 0 as int))))

Si observas la salida propuesta, se relaciona la base A con alias a y ya no tienes que preocuparte más de la concatenación del valor de @archivo1 con la base B con alias b.

Luego la restricción y nombres de columnas ya los haces con el alias asignado.

Además, tratar con cadenas de texto en las querys dinámicas, te supone utilizar dobles o triples apóstrofes. Para la solución, lo más fácil, es utilizar la variable @COEFICIENTE como un varchar, y castear su contenido en el where.

Para generar las columnas del archivo2 que son las que quieres visualizar, utilizas `Select b.*`. Así no te aparecen también las de la tabla a.

Answer (score 0):

No ibas muy desencaminado, yo apuntaría cuatro cosas en tu intento.

1. Mejor utilizar un `JOIN`, que es la forma estandarizada para mostrar (combinar) el contenido de dos tablas con un campo común.
2. El enunciado dice que el campo2 de una tabla debe ser mayor o igual que el de otra tabla multiplicado por la variable, fila a fila, por o que el `SUM` que has puesto no es necesario.
3. Con la variable `@Script` estás construyendo un `varchar`, por lo que cuando concatenas la variable `@COEFICIENTE`, que es un entero, lo debes pasar a `varchar`.
4. Es habitual y recomendable utilizar alias en las consultas para una mejor legibilidad.

   ```
   SET @Script = N'SELECT * 
     FROM [Base].[dbo].['+ @ARCHIVO1 + '] a'
     INNER JOIN [Base].[dbo].['+ @ARCHIVO2 + '] b on a.ID = b.ID
     AND b.campo2 >= a.campo2 * ' + CAST(@COEFiCIENTE as varchar) 

   EXEC (@Script)
   ```

Comment: muchas gracias a ambos, se entendió perfectamente y se ejecutó sin problemas pero cuando intento guardarlo en un archivo rechaza la sentencia INTO imagino que es por se encuentra dentro de la variable @SCRIPT